# Jenkins integration with Active Directory has very slow performance for most of the users

Tags: performance, jenkins, active-directory, ldap

We configured our Jenkins to use the AD using LDAP plugin and AD plugin (Both), for most of the users the Jenkins then works very slow (Sometimes login or opening new link takes few minutes) while some have reasonable performance.

I checked using the /whoAmI option, and found that a user with good performance was connected to "Domain users" group, while a user with bad performance was instead connected to "authenticated" group (Which does not exist on the AD).
Both users are on the "Domain users" group in AD, but Jenkins does not recognize it on the users with slow performance. (And it identified the "authenticated" group which does not exist in AD, and does not appear with the user with good performance).

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Have you reviewed the cloudbees discussion for [AD](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/235991547-The-log-in-with-AD-plugin-is-very-slow) and [LDAP](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/235216188-The-log-in-with-LDAP-plugin-is-very-slow) ?

Comment: Yes, it did not helped much

Answer (score 4):

Finally the answer was in another link of cloudbees- 
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218625237-How-to-diagnose-AD-integration-problems-

Issue number 1-  Jenkins should use global catalog (ports 3268/3269) and not LDAP catalog (ports 389/636), after I switched to global catalog problems were resolved